# Can I change elasticsearch docker container default password `changeme` automatically?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Is running the following command manually after the container is newly created the only way to change the elasticsearch X-pack default password `changeme`?([reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)) :

```
docker exec -it elasticsearch curl -XPUT -u elastic 'elasticsearch:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "somePassword"
}'
```

Is it possible to do it automatically in `docker-compose` or `Dockerfile`? I only need it to run once when the container is newly created. 
I've tried the `command` key in `docker-compose` but it doesn't wait until the container is fully started to run.

I've also tried Dockerfile

```
COPY ./docker-misc/docker-entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

but I don't need it to run everytime the container is restarted. I only need it to run when the elasticsearch image is newly created.

Comment: I looked into this before and couldn't find a solution using the docker-compose config (maybe there is one, but I couldn't find it!). However, the docker-entrypoint solution seems good -- I would change the script to touch a file after running the command, and only run the command, if the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Also I would consider to use a different filename, and append it to the end of docker-entrypoint.sh (that way if you upgrade to a new base image, you don't have to worry about integrating changes to docker-entrypoint.sh in the new version).

Comment: @dshockley the 6.0 version released a few days ago uses the environment variable `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` to set the password, but the doc says it's only limited to `platinum` version

Comment: Yes, I saw that yesterday, it's awesome. :)